# How to write stored procedure in DB2

Tags: db2

Please Help me in to write the stored procedure in Db2.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE assedt
BEGIN 

 SELECT ASSETNUM FROM ASSET
END
```

I tried the above code it is throwing an error like below:

> Error report -
>   DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=SELECT ASSETNUM;ROCEDURE p1
>   BEGIN
>
> ;, DRIVER=4.12.55

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DB2 9.7 SQL syntax, what am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964538/db2-9-7-sql-syntax-what-am-i-doing-wrong)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The following redbook: http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg248326.html?Open, is written for Db2 for IBM i (not zOS, not LUW), but chapter 2 is a great introduction to DB2 Procedural SQL and it is applicable to the other DB2s.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Link-only answers become useless when the links go stale; please consider adding salient points from your link in your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.  I tried the link and it opens correctly.  Anyway, I edited the answer changing the link.

Comment: Please consider reading [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/222193)

Comment: Thanks @mustaccio.  I get your point and I will take it into account for next time.   Given the provided question, I though that the user may get benefited of the referenced book, which is quite unknown outside IBM i (iSeries or AS/400) world but have a very easy to follow procedural Db2 explanation in its second chapter, that is valid on other Db2 platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
create table test_table (numcol integer);

insert into test_table values (1);

CREATE OR REPLACE procedure assedt (out out_var integer)
language sql
p1: begin
declare l_var integer;
   select max(numcol) into l_var from test_table;
   set out_var = l_var + 1;
end p1;

begin
declare g_var integer;
call assedt( g_var );
insert into test_table values (g_var);
end;

select * from test_table;
```

Explanation, per G_V's suggestion: this procedure, somewhat styled as your original, takes a max value from test_table, increments it, and returns it in the out parameter (a-la Oracle's nextval()). The anonymous block after the procedure, executes the proc, grabs the new maximum and then inserts it back into the test_table outside the proc. This gives you the perspective of interaction between stored code and anonymous code, and how you can pass values and parameters. Hope this helps.

Comment: While it's good that you're posting a practical example, some explanation as to what it does or why would be nice.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are missing a Colon after "P1". It should be "P1:" 
Checkout this [site](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_10.0.1/basic/H_EXAMPLE_DB2_STORED_PROCEDURE_IN_SQL_1694_OVER.html) for the sample example